# Repeat the Program Prompt

Tags: c

The current problem is with the `Evaluate another interval (Y/N)?` prompt. Let's say I run the program 4 times; in order to end it, it requires me to type `N` 4 times.

```
int main() {
    int trap, test;
    double low, hi;
    char repeat, c;

    //Gather End Points
    do {
        printf("Enter endpoints of interval to be integrated (low hi): ");
        test = scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &hi);

        if (test != 2) {
            printf("Error: Improperly formatted input\n");
            while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);  //Discard extra characters
        } else       
        if (low > hi)
            printf("Error: low must be < hi\n");

    } while ((test != 2 || low > hi));

    //Gather amount of triangles
    do {         
        printf("Enter number of trapezoids to be used: ");
        test = scanf("%d", &trap);

        if (test != 1) {
            printf("Error: Improperly formated input\n");
            while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); //Discard extra characters
        } else
        if (trap < 1)
            printf("Error: numT must be >= 1\n");

    } while ((trap < 1 || test != 1));

    //Output integrate
    printf("Using %d trapezoids, integral between %lf and %lf is %lf",
           trap, low, hi, integrate(low, hi, trap));   

    //Prompt user for another time
    while (1) {
        printf("\nEvaluate another interval (Y/N)? ");
        scanf(" %c", &repeat);

        switch (repeat) {
          case 'Y':
            main();
          case 'y':
            main();
          case 'N':
            return 0;
          case 'n':
            return 0;
          default:
            printf("Error: must enter Y or N");
        }
    }             
    return 0;
}
```

I expect it so that no matter what run of the program I'm on it will close when I type one `N`.

Comment: You really should be iterating, not recursing, since each time you recurse you're needlessly adding a stack frame.  Move the code that does the work *out* of `main`, and call it from `main` in a loop, prompting for more.  But your actual bug is due to the fact that your first case, for `Y`, is falling through to the case for `y`.  Just add `breaks` after those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your program:

- You test the return value of `scanf()` when reading the user's answer to the prompts, and you clear the pending input correctly, but you do not handle the potential end of file, leading to endless loops.
- `c` must be defined as `int` to accommodate for all values returned by `getchar()`: 256 values of type `unsigned char` and the special value `EOF`.
- You can `main()` recursively to repeat the program's action requiring multiple `N` answers. You should instead add an outer loop and exit from it upon a `N` answer or an end of file condition.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double integrate(double low, double hi, int trap) {
    ...
}

int flush_line(void) {
    // Consume the pending input and return `'\n`` or `EOF`
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

int main() {
    // Main program loop
    for (;;) {
        int trap, test;
        double low, hi;
        char repeat;

        //Gather End Points
        for (;;) {
            printf("Enter endpoints of interval to be integrated (low hi): ");
            test = scanf("%lf %lf", &low, &hi);
            if (test == EOF)
                return 1;
            if (test != 2) {
                printf("Error: Improperly formatted input\n");
                if (flush_line() == EOF)
                    return 1;
                continue;  // ask again
            }
            if (low > hi) {
                printf("Error: low must be < hi\n");
                continue;
            }
            break;  // input is valid
        }

        //Gather amount of triangles
        for (;;) {         
            printf("Enter number of trapezoids to be used: ");
            test = scanf("%d", &trap);
            if (test == EOF)
                return 1;
            if (test != 1) {
                printf("Error: Improperly formated input\n");
                if (flush_line() == EOF)
                    return 1;
                continue;
            }
            if (trap < 1) {
                printf("Error: numT must be >= 1\n");
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        //Output integrate
        printf("Using %d trapezoids, integral between %lf and %lf is %lf\n",
               trap, low, hi, integrate(low, hi, trap));

        //Prompt user for another time
        for (;;) {
            printf("\nEvaluate another interval (Y/N)? ");
            if (scanf(" %c", &repeat) != 1)
                return 1;  // unexpected end of file

            switch (repeat) {
              case 'Y':
              case 'y':
                break;
              case 'N':
              case 'n':
                return 0;
              default:
                printf("Error: must enter Y or N\n");
                if (flush_line() == EOF)
                    return 1;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you want but calling `main` recursively is not a good idea.

A pretty simple way to change your program is to add an additional `while(1)` level. Something like:

```
int main(void) 
{
    char repeat;
    while(1){       // Outer while to keep the program running

        printf("running program\n");

        // Put your program here

        printf("program done\n");

        repeat = '?';
        while(repeat != 'y' && repeat != 'Y'){  // Repeat until input is 'Y' or 'y'
            printf("\nEvaluate another interval (Y/N)? ");
            scanf(" %c", &repeat);

            switch (repeat){
                case 'Y':
                case 'y':
                    break;
                case 'N':
                case 'n':
                    return 0;   // Stop if input is 'n' or 'N'
               default:
                   printf("Error: must enter Y or N");
            }    
        }
    }

    return 0;  // This will never be reached
}
```

Another way (a simpler way, IMO) is to put the code where you ask the user into a function that you call from `main`. Like:

```
int continueProg()
{
    char repeat = '?';
    while(1){
        printf("\nEvaluate another interval (Y/N)? ");
        scanf(" %c", &repeat);

        switch (repeat){
            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
                return 1;;
            case 'N':
            case 'n':
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Error: must enter Y or N");
        }    
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    do {

        printf("running program\n");

        // Put your program here

        printf("program done\n");

    } while(continueProg());

    return 0;
}
```

BTW: Take a look at `getchar` instead of using `scanf`

Comment: You should test the return value of `scanf(" %c", &repeat);` to avoid looping endlessly if the input stream has reached end of file without a `Y/N` answer.